# Having a constexpr static string gives a linker error

Tags: c++, string, c++11, constexpr, type-traits

The following program gives me a link-time error:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Test { static constexpr char text[] = "Text"; };

int main()
{
    std::cout << Test::text << std::endl; // error: undefined reference to `Test::text'
}
```

The error message is

```
/tmp/main-35f287.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x4): undefined reference to `Test::text'
main.cpp:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `Test::text'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Ok. Let's try to fix that: I add a definition outside the `struct` body:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Test { static constexpr char text[] = "Text"; };
constexpr char Test::text[] = "Text";

int main()
{
    std::cout << Test::text << std::endl;
}
```

Clang gives me the following error message.

```
main.cpp:4:35: error: static data member 'text' already has an initializer
    constexpr char Test::text[] = "Text";
                                  ^
main.cpp:3:50: note: previous initialization is here
    struct Test { static constexpr char text[] = "Text"; };
```

Oh, well, I thought, now I know what you want:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Test { static constexpr char text[]; };
constexpr char Test::text[] = "Text";

int main()
{
    std::cout << Test::text << std::endl;
}
```

And again an error:

```
main.cpp:3:41: error: declaration of constexpr static data member 'text' requires an initializer
    struct Test { static constexpr char text[]; };
```

And there the dog bites its own tail. :(

Is there a way to use compile-time constant character arrays that are declared inside a class? The reason, I want the data inside a class, is that I need a type traits class that helps me do template stuff.

Comment: Did you mean simply `struct Test { static const char text[] = "Text"; };
`?

Comment: You have tried two options - initializer outside the class, both inside and outside. Now, there is a third alternative...

Comment: This works fine: `struct Test { static constexpr auto text = "Text"; };`

Comment: @vincentp Nice. This is the most concise way of writing it. Avoids duplication. Worthy to be an accepted answer.

Comment: @vincentp follows up with your comment, I asked this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34793392/different-behavior-observed-with-constexpr-auto-char-array-variable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Should work:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Test { static constexpr char text[] = "Text"; };
constexpr char Test::text[];

int main()
{
    std::cout << Test::text << std::endl;
}
```

In standard (n4140 §9.4.2/3) you can find:

> ***A static data member of literal type can be declared in the class
>   definition with the constexpr specifier***; if so, its declaration shall
>   specify a brace-or-equal-initializer in which every initializer-clause
>   that is an assignment-expression is a constant expression. [ Note: In
>   both these cases, the member may appear in constant expressions. —end
>   note ] ***The member shall still be defined in a namespace scope if it is
>   odr-used (3.2) in the program and the namespace scope definition shall
>   not contain an initializer***.

Comment: Only one initialization initialization assignment.

Comment: Works for me! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As said in comments, this version works fine:

```
struct Test { static constexpr auto text = "Text"; };
```

But `text` will be a `const char*` instead of a `char[]`.

Comment: Why does it not work to make a `const char[5]` out of it? I mean why is there so much of a difference? This is annoying. That makes it unusable for my purposes.