# Different behavior observed with constexpr auto/char-array variable

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, constexpr, auto

Following up with this question [Having a constexpr static string gives a linker error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34792403/having-a-constexpr-static-string-gives-a-linker-error#34792443)

In the question, this code wasn't able to compile:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Test { static constexpr char text[] = "Text"; };

int main()
{
    std::cout << Test::text << std::endl; // error: undefined reference to `Test::text'
}
```

From the comment, this code is able to compile:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Test { static constexpr auto text = "Text"; };

int main()
{
    std::cout << Test::text << std::endl;
}
```

My question is why the `auto` version works but the array of `char` version doesn't?

Could you please point out the statement in the standard allowing the second version and disallowing the first?

I took a look at [Strange behavior with constexpr static member variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28530583/strange-behavior-with-constexpr-static-member-variable) but it seems to be another question.

Comment: It is same question and same accepted answer is valid: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28534978/113662 i.e. both versions are ill-formed but compiler is not obliged to reject them and it chooses to accept one of them

Comment: @TadeuszKopec No, the latter isn't ill-formed.

Comment: @TadeuszKopec I missed the answer of Sahu, which is the addition to the accepted answer. In Sahu's answer, the literal type was mentioned. And, I misunderstood that, text will be deduced char[] instead of char*

Comment: @Columbo you are right, the mentioned exception applies here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A declaration of a static data member in class is never a definition.
The difference between your examples is that only one requires a definition of `text`.

The `auto` version deduces `char const*`, hence `text` is only subject to an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion and not odr-used. By contrast, the first code effectively passes `text`'s address, odr-use-ing it - i.e. necessitating a definition.

Comment: Yeah, the key is `text` is deduced `char const*` instead of `char[]`. I misunderstood that point.

Comment: Isn't `const char*` an address? I'm confused.

Comment: @Lingxi No, `const char*` is a pointer type. The object of this pointer type passed to the corresponding `operator<<` overload represents the address of the first `char` in `text`, though.

Comment: Oh I see. In the second version, no address-taking operation. In the first version, array-to-pointer conversion involves address taking and is thus ODR-use.

Comment: @Lingxi Well, there are exceptions. For instance, writing `std::cout << Test::text[0];` is not an odr-use, although `text`'s address is implicitly taken. In general, however, that is correct.-

Comment: @Columbo In general, the increasing complexity of C++ has blown me away. Really admire your expertise in C++~

Answer (score 2):

```
struct Test { static constexpr auto text = "Text"; };
```

resolves to

```
struct Test { static constexpr const char * text = "Text"; };
```

So the second expression is a `constexpr` value of a pointer not an array.